# What is the correct command to create a volume with a specific size with the storcli utility?

Tags: command-line, raid, megaraid, storcli

On a LSI (avago tech) controller, how does one create a volume that is 10 gigabytes large using the command line utility storcli?

The help states there is a parameter called size, but that fails to recognize the size in bytes.

```
 $ storcli /c0 vd help
 Storage Command Line Tool  Ver 1.17.08 September 10, 2015
 (c)Copyright 2015, AVAGO Corporation, All Rights Reserved.


storcli /cx add vd r[0|1|5|6|00|10|50|60]
        [Size=<VD1_Sz>,<VD2_Sz>,..|all] [name=<VDNAME1>,..]
        drives=e:s|e:s-x|e:s-x,y,e:s-x,y,z [PDperArray=x][SED]
        [pdcache=on|off|default][pi][DimmerSwitch(ds)=default|automatic(auto)|
        none|maximum(max)|MaximumWithoutCaching(maxnocache)][WT|WB|AWB][nora|ra]
        [direct|cached] [cachevd] [Strip=<8|16|32|64|128|256|512|1024>]
         [AfterVd=X] [EmulationType=0|1|2] [Spares = [e:]s|[e:]s-x|[e:]s-x,y]
        [force][ExclusiveAccess] [Cbsize=0|1|2 Cbmode=0|1|2|3|4|7]
```

The command line utility produces an incorrect or confusing error message when the size parameter is specified with a suffix (e.g 10g) or in bytes:

```
$ storcli /c0 add vd r6 size=10737418240 name=test  drives=3,16:12-19
syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_UNKNOWN, expecting TOKEN_DRIVES    
     Storage Command Line Tool  Ver 1.17.08 September 10, 2015
     (c)Copyright 2015, AVAGO Corporation, All Rights Reserved.
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to use gb instead of g. Originally, I had also placed the size option in a different spot and got the same error as you.

```
Storage Command Line Tool  Ver 1.20.15 July 29 2016
[root@vmware:/opt/lsi/storcli] ./storcli /c0 add vd raid1 size=100gb
name=RAID1-D drives=252:0-1
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Add VD Succeeded
```

Comment: The order of arguments matters with that utility!

Answer (score 0):

To create a volume with a custom size, specify the size in megabytes:

```
$ storcli /c0 add vd r6 Size=100 name=test  drives=3,16:12-19   
$ storcli /c0/v0 show
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC     Size Name
0/0   RAID6 Optl  RW     Yes     RWTD  -   ON  99.75 MB test
```

---

### Submitting an issue does not work at Avagotech (see picture), so I'm going to do it here and hope that someone over there notices.

Regarding the storcli utility.

I am trying to add a virtual drive on a configuration consisting of megaraid 9271-i8, an entel expander board and the cachecade module. My intention is to create a virtual device with type=raid6 allocating only 10gb. According to the manual (see link), this is acheived with for example:

storcli /c0 add vd r6 size=10737418240 name=test  drives=3,16:12-19

this would exit with a confusing message: "syntax error, unexpected TOKEN_UNKNOWN, expecting TOKEN_DRIVES" .  Piror to that I tried with size=10g and that failed with the same message. While writing this, I though perhaps size was expecting a percentage so I specified size=10 and ended up creating a 10 megabyte volume.

Please consider my suggestions to improve the user-friendliness of the cli tool:

- add support for specifying the volume size with suffixes such as "10g",  "10000m" with capital and lowercase letters.
- add suppport for  specifying the size or a volume with a percentage
- update the argument parser and give a meaningfull message when a large value is passed such as "volume size out of range, please sepecify the size in megabytes"

Aditionally, I find the command-was-sucessful messages to be superfluous. Please consider making the output more terse and avoid noise like:

```
$ storcli /c0/v0 show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None
(...)

$ storcli /c0 add vd r6 Size=10 name=test  drives=3,16:12-19
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Add VD Succeeded
(...)
```

Thank you!

manual: http://www.sp-it.net/drivers/lsi/lsi_9271i/tools/1.02.08_storcli_phase3/storcli_phase3_refmanual.pdf

---

[image: form submission fails]